# is not Thread-Safe for Bill Pugh Singleton?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

I thought 'Thread safe' was an instance lock
But writing the test code did not produce the desired results.

The result I want should be square like this.

```
singleton new instance
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

This is the code I wrote when testing.

```
public class main extends Thread{

    String name = "";

    public main(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BillPughSingleton.getInstance().addNum(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
            new main(i+"").start();
    }

}

public class BillPughSingleton {

    private BillPughSingleton() {}

    private static class BillPughSingletonHolder{
        private static BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
        static {
            System.out.println("singleton new instance");
        }
    }

    public static BillPughSingleton getInstance() {
        return BillPughSingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    //Adding 'synchronized' to it result I want.
    public void addNum(String name) {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i ++)
            System.out.print(name+" ");

        System.out.println(); // \n
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I misunderstand 'Thread-safe'.
Thank you!

Comment: What output did you expect? What do you mean with " 'Thread safe' was an instance lock"? Why are you surprised that adding `synchronized` did produce the result the you want?

Comment: I know 'thread-safe' can only access one thread per instance, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. It just means that your code works correctly in the presence of multiple threads. Whether that is by using `synchronized`, `volatile` or any other concurrency mechanism. But can you answer my first questions?

Comment: I thought it was an instance lock because a singleton could only access one thread.
But I think I was wrong. Thanks for the answer!